# How to get ISO8601-presentation for date using ICU-string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, icu, intl

Are there a robust and crutch-less way to print `Date` inside the [ICU-message](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) string, using [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format - `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`?

**Subquestion 1**: are other *custom* format string supported?

**Subquestion 2**: why [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) doesn't support custom formatting?

#### Details and observations

I want to use [ICU-messages](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) for i18n features for the javascript application. There are at least two packages on NPM, allowing to format message-strings:

- [intl-messageformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-messageformat)
- [format-message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-message)

Each has some kind of `formatMessageFunction`, accepting the raw ICU-message, the name of locale and data for applying. But both uses [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) (looks, like it is the industry standard):

- [Proof for Intl-Messageformat](https://github.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat/blob/v1.3.0/src/compiler.js#L101)
- [Proof for format-message](https://github.com/format-message/format-message/blob/v5.0.0/packages/format-message-interpret/index.js#L82)

and it can't format dates using custom format.

Despite the described limitations of mentioned implementations, the ICU **[describes a way of *custom formatting for dates*](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-SimpleDateFormat)**

#### Example

My ICU-string:

```
var icu_string = `Hello,
    <strong>{username}</strong>,
    it is
    <time datetime="{ts, date, ???}">{ts, date}</time>
    `;
```

Sample code:

```js
var IntlMessageFormat = require('intl-messageformat'); // no matter, which NPM package to use
var formatter = new IntlMessageFormat(icu_string, 'en');
var output = formatter.format({
    username: 'Barack Obama',
    ts: new Date()
});
console.log(output);
```

The desirable output is `Hello, <strong>Barack Obama</strong>, it is
 <time datetime="2016-10-25T01:01:15Z">Oct 25, 2016</time>`

> You could test current behavior here: [format-message.github.io](http://format-message.github.io/icu-message-format-for-translators/editor.html)

#### Similar questions

- [question about ISO and ICU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25050034/1115187). But I don't want to play with `locale` parameter (the code will use the selected locale for translation).

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is to pass in the timestamp pre-formatted. At least for ISO timestamps, you can pass `date.toISOString()` as a separate parameter to the message.

```
var IntlMessageFormat = require('intl-messageformat'); // no matter, which NPM package to use
var icu_string = 'Hello, {username}, it is {ts, date} (ISO-timestamp  is {tsiso})'
var formatter = new IntlMessageFormat(icu_string, 'en');
var date = new Date();
var output = formatter.format({
    username: 'Barack Obama',
    ts: date,
    tsiso: date.toISOString()
});
console.log(output);
```

Both [intl-messageformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-messageformat#user-defined-formats) and [format-message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-message#formatmessagesetupoptions) have a way to define a custom format, based however on [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) options, instead of ICU's [SimpleDateFormat](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-SimpleDateFormat).

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and for `format-message` too)! But the main flaw of `a custom format, based however on Intl.DateTimeFormat` is a restricted set of customizations. Intl.DateTimeFormat has really limited set of options: `two or one decimals in the month`.. Seriously, it has a deep base (thanks CLDR), but **it is not enough for real applications**, IMO

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at closure, goog.i18n.DateTimeFormat: 
https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.i18n.DateTimeFormat.html

It uses a subset of the ICU patterns (in the above link click "VIEW SOURCE", and see doc from line 33)

Warning: using your own pattern means you become responsible to "get it right", as you throw away the stuff that the library "knows" about the proper locale formatting.

What are you trying to achieve that the intl stuff doesn't support?

Comment: Thanks for an answer! Looks, like with this date-functionality I should take the entire Closure toolchain into my project. It is the first flaw (for me). The other issue: _subset_ of ICU string is not a full ICU-engine. I really like [format-message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-message) and [messageformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/messageformat) just because ICU fully supported. And I don't know how to convert string from my example with *Closure*..

Comment: About use cases: html tag `<time datetime="UTC time">HUMAN-readable time</time>` - the same date is written twice in different formats