# Get ISO string from a date without time zone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

My configuration is Lisbon time zone. When I do `new Date()` I get my current local date/time which is `Fri Apr 28 2017 01:10:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

When I get the ISO string with `toISOString()` it will apply the time zone and I will get:

```
2017-04-28T00:10:55.964Z
```

The problem is that some minutes ago the date time was like this (yesterday):

```
2017-04-27T23:45:05.654Z
```

I tried moment.js (new to this) and I did something like this

```
document.write(moment('2017-04-28').format())
```

But I get this `2017-04-28T00:00:00+01:00` which is not `2017-04-28T00:00:00.000Z`

I want to pass this value as a parameter of a restful method to parse it automatically as a DateTime type, but if I pass the output from moment.js format then it will get parsed as `2017-04-27 23:00:00.00`

If I create a new date with `new Date()` or with `new Date('2017-04-27')` (date portion),  I just want to get the ISO format like as follows with no time zone:

```
2017-04-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

Is there a javascript method like toISOString() or using maybe moment to get that format?

No matter what time zone or moment of day, I just to simulate that is midnight of the date given.

Comment: A date/time value with no timezone is (usually) not useful, unless the time zone is **assumed** to be something in particular (like UTC). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 33):

It's very unclear what you're asking. If you want the UTC date with the hours always 0, then set the UTC hours to 0 and use *toISOString*, e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

Of course this is going to show the UTC date, which may be different to the date on the system that generated the Date.

Also,

```
new Date('2017-04-27').toISOString();
```

**should** return 2017-04-27T00:00:00Z (i.e. it should be parsed as UTC according to ECMA-262, which is contrary to ISO 8601 which would treat it as local), however that is not reliable in all implementations in use.

If you just want to get the current date in ISO 8601 format, you can do:

```js
if (!Date.prototype.toISODate) {
  Date.prototype.toISODate = function() {
    return this.getFullYear() + '-' +
           ('0'+ (this.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
           ('0'+ this.getDate()).slice(-2);
  }
}

console.log(new Date().toISODate());
```

However, since the built-in *toISOString* uses UTC this might be confusing. If the UTC date is required, then:

```js
if (!Date.prototype.toUTCDate) {
  Date.prototype.toUTCDate = function() {
    return this.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
           ('0'+ (this.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
           ('0'+ this.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
  }
}

console.log(new Date().toUTCDate());
```

Comment: This helped me. I was looking for the current client side UTC date (without timezone or timestamp).

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, your "easier" version is not doing the same thing, because your substring will be taken from the UTC instead of the local date and this will be different for some ours a day.

Comment: Ah yes, of course.  Thanks for the catch.  I've deleted my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 20):

old_date = Fri Jan 08 2021 16:01:30 GMT+0900

```
const new_date = old_date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

new_date = "2021-01-08"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please discuss especially why you propose exactly the solution discussed in a the most upvoted older existing answer as not reliable. I.e. your contribution is not new and you'd have to point out its advantages in contrast to the current notion that it has disadvantages. There is also another older answer, not upvoted though, which proposes the same as yours, just with at least a linkg to some info. Copying other answers, or reposting them for lack of reading the existing answers, is not appreciated here, because it does not provide additional value to the Q/A collection.

Comment: Just trying to provide a simple solution here. I didn't have a lot of time and definitely didn't copy and paste it from someone else. If fact there isn't an answer given like mine above, although on reading through again, someone has put something similar in the comments. Feel free to edit this to add an explanation if you have more time than I do, if not I will just leave it here for anyone who might find it useful (and doesn't have a lot of time to read through an explanation of why my solution is better or worse than any of the others)

Comment: This one liner is clear enough for any JavaScript developer to know what's going on. Simple and effective, it's just removing the unwanted time characters of the date string. I wonder why no one came with this solution before. I cannot see that older answer where this solution is reportedly already answered.

Comment: However I do agree it needs further styling polish. The first and last lines should be part of the code block. 1st line: `const old_date = new Date("Fri Jan 08 2021 16:01:30 GMT+0900");`. Last line: `console.log(new_date); // "2021-01-08"`. And, even when the solution is self-explanatory, a 1-line intro would better present the solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve this by simply formating everything that you need in place using `moment.format()` and then simply append the extra Z to the string. You have to do this as Z within moment JS is reserved for outputting.

```
var date = moment('2014-08-28').format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000") + "Z";
```

Fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/2avxxz6q/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it is not The output is 2017-04-27T23:00:00.000Z and I looking 2017-04-28T00:00:00.000Z. Today for me is already April 28 and not April 27.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an alternative if your not worried about the time component

Comment: Changed it again and tested output here https://jsfiddle.net/2avxxz6q/ @MaximusDecimus

Answer (score 10):

you can try this, it works for me!
you will have the  **ISO format** **without timeZone** effect

Fri Jan 01 2021 **23:10:00 GMT+0100** => 2021-01-01T**23:10:00.000Z**

```js
function isoDateWithoutTimeZone(date) {
  if (date == null) return date;
  var timestamp = date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  var correctDate = new Date(timestamp);
  // correctDate.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // uncomment this if you want to remove the time
  return correctDate.toISOString();
}


        var now= new Date("01-01-2021 23:10:00");
        console.log(now.toString());
        var returnedDate = isoDateWithoutTimeZone(now);
        console.log(returnedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `moment.js` library, you can just parse and connect date components. For example

```
type Components = {
  day: number,
  month: number,
  year: number
}

export default class DateFormatter {
  // 2018-11-11T00:00:00
  static ISOStringWithoutTimeZone = (date: Date): string => {
    const components = DateFormatter.format(DateFormatter.components(date))
    return `${components.year}-${components.month}-${components.day}T00:00:00`
  }

  static format = (components: Components) => {
    return {
      day: `${components.day}`.padStart(2, '0'),
      month: `${components.month}`.padStart(2, '0'),
      year: components.year
    }
  }

  static components = (date: Date): Components => {
    return {
      day: date.getDate(),
      month: date.getMonth() + 1,
      year: date.getFullYear()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While you might not need moment, this set of code really looks like it's tending towards remaking the wheel for a 3.2kb gzip I'd still take moment.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple function that extends moment js objects:

```
moment.fn.toISOStringWithoutTimezone = function () {
  return this.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss");
};
```

It can be used like

```
moment().toISOStringWithoutTimezone();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another tricky way you can use it, AFAIK from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050034/get-iso-8601-using-intl-datetimeformat#answer-69032104) answer. In Swedish date format you can convert your date easily to Iso format like below:

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE').format(new Date());//'2022-07-08'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

```
moment().toISOString(keepOffset);
```

Comment: You saved me, awesome solution to keep offset!

Answer (score 1):

**My issue**: I need to send the date and time into ISO format to the server API all the time.
To solve this issue, I could have simple used the new Date().toISOString() but my client app could be running under different time zone hence there would be time zone difference all the time.

**Solution:** To solve this issue, I referred the solution given above i.e. manually create the ISO format string regardless given time zone.

```
function getISOString(date)
{
let d = new Date(date),
month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
day = '' + d.getDate(),
year = ''+ d.getFullYear(),
hours = ''+d.getHours(),
minutes = ''+d.getMinutes(),
seconds = ''+d.getSeconds();
month = month.length < 2? '0' + month : month;
day   = day.length < 2? '0' + day : day;
hours = hours.length < 2?'0'+hours:hours;
minutes = minutes.length< 2? '0'+minutes:minutes;
seconds = seconds.length< 2? '0'+seconds:seconds;
return ( [year, month, day].join('-')+'T'+[hours,minutes,seconds].join(':')+'.000');
}
console.log(getISOString(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wish to get the current date in ISO 8601 to pass it to your API? 
Maybe using a moment.js wrapper for native JavaScript mentioned [here](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/) might help?

As in your example:

```
document.write(moment('01/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).toISOString());
```

Snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  var displaysTime = $('#divTime');
  displaysTime.text(moment.utc('27/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).toISOString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divTime">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want ISOString of start of the date irrespective of time

(ie) Time zone should be'T00:00:00.000Z' more matter what date you choose.

I dont think there is a straight function without using any plugin.

So i created a function to fullfill your need,If this is what you are looking for

```js
function mimicISOString(date) {
    let d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-') +'T00:00:00.000Z';
}

console.log(mimicISOString(new Date()));
```

This will return current date with start of the time zone.If this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Date to be in UTC time (00:00:00) you can use:

```
moment.utc('2017-04-28').toISOString() // 2017-04-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions for you....

Initially, I wrote a small piece of JavaScript (okay, okay, *Typescript*) which took a `Date` value and converted it into an ISO date string, like this:

```
createDateString(dateStr) {     
  //  Take a Date value, and turn it into a "2005-05-26T11:37:42" string
  var tzoffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
  var currentDate = new Date(dateStr);
  var withTimezone = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - tzoffset);
  var localISOTime = withTimezone.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('Z', '');
  return localISOTime;
}
```

This worked perfectly... until it was deployed onto a server.  Then, I noticed that it was getting the timezone wrong.

My solution (without resorting to third-party products) was to rewrite it like this:

```
padZero(numericValue) {
  if (numericValue < 10)
      return '0' + numericValue.toString();;
     
  return numericValue.toString();;
}
createDateString(date) {     
  //  Take a Date value, and turn it into a "2005-05-26T11:37:42" string
  var dateStr = date.getFullYear() + '-' + 
        this.padZero(date.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
        this.padZero(date.getDate()) + 'T' +
        this.padZero(date.getHours()) + ':' + 
        this.padZero(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + 
        this.padZero(date.getSeconds());

  return dateStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> new Date('2019-04-27').toISOString();

also you can use dayjs: https://day.js.org/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30651161)

Answer (score 0):

Date formatting is not a main problem.
The whole question is based on a relatively wrong premise.

For a start it is necessary to realize what could be a Date.

*First alternative is: **"What time I see on my watches"***
That is "relative date" because I see 11:00 at Europe at different time that somebody sees 11:00 at US

*Second alternative is: **"Point to specific moment in time"***
That could be named "absolute date" and most important for this view is unix timestamp. The timestamp is ticking synchronously at whole world, although different people see different time at their watches.

So, `2017-04-28T00:10:55.964Z` is equal to timestamp **`1493338255`** *(btw `Z` in date string means: this is time at GMT)*. The same timestamp has `2017-04-28T01:10:55.964+01:00`, `2017-04-28T09:10:55.964+09:00`, `2017-04-27T16:10:55.964-08:00`, etc.

That means: *ISODateString says what time I see at my watches and how far away I am from Greenwich*

**And now implementation.**
It is really important to say what do you need.

Let's have a set of hourly events.

Now guy from US coming and asking: *"what happened yesterday?"*
What should be at response?

There are 2 possibilities again:

1. **What happened during his day `2017-04-28T00:00:00-08:00 ... 2017-04-28T23:59:59-08:00`**
   It means `2017-04-28T08:00:00Z .. 2017-04-29T07:59:59Z` and it is correct, because this is an actual day range of US people's
2. **What happened during calendar day `2017-04-28`**
   You can want some globally statistic and it is
   required to see the same at US as well as Japan.
   **Solution is really simple - just drop time-shift `-08:00` from question.**
   `moment('2017-04-28').format(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss)` should make something like this:
   `2017-04-28T00:00:00 ... 2017-04-28T23:59:59`

Just be careful, **that is NOT an ISODateTime** and you have to handle it right at the API!

Answer (score 0):

```js
moment('2017-04-28').utcOffset(0, true).toISOString()
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are saying you'd like to get the current date in Lisbon:

```
moment().tz("Europe/Lisbon").format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You can see that this works the way you think it should:

```
moment('2017-04-28T00:00:00+01:00').tz("Europe/Lisbon").format('YYYY-MM-DD') //"2017-04-28"
```